# Create an error check for a function based on numeric data type?

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function that can show a specific error message, when I make a mistake. Does anyone know how to do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

#### For Example

```r
newFunction <- function(a) {
for(i in 1:a) {
a <- i^2
print(a) 
}}

newFunction('five')
```

I would like to get an error message, such as "Stop! Variable is non-numerical"

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether the input is numeric with `is.numeric()` and use `stop()` if it isn't

e.g.

```
if(!is.numeric(a)) {
  stop("Stop! Variable is non-numerical")
}
```